# Chart.js AngularJS size option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I have the following HTML:

```
    <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" data="activity_data"
        labels="activity_label" legend="true" series="activity_series"             click="onClick">
</canvas>
```

This gives me a chart with the height and width of my full screen.

Now of course I will need to make this smaller.

So I attempted:

```
            <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" data="activity_data"
            labels="activity_label" legend="true" series="activity_series"             click="onClick"
 style="height: 400px;">
    </canvas>
```

No changes

Then

```
    <canvas id="line" height="400" class="chart chart-line" data="activity_data"
        labels="activity_label" legend="true" series="activity_series"             click="onClick">
</canvas>
```

No changes

Then I tried using the options function:

```
        <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" data="activity_data"
            labels="activity_label" legend="true" series="activity_series"             click="onClick"
 options="{height: 400}">
    </canvas>
```

Once again this had no effect.

So my question is what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try wrapping this up with a div and setting a height to the div?

Comment: @anpsmn i have not tried that yet no